# How to fill Smyfony CollectionType with N forms based on Database Rows

Tags: php, symfony

I have a CollectionType of EditAnnouncementType typeform I have created. This CollectionType will be used to render a form to handle a user editing some text of an Announcement, where each announcement has its own Edit modal that opens (the modals have unique ID's)

```
$editForm = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('editForms', CollectionType::class,
            [
                'entry_type' => EditAnnouncementType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'required' => false,
        ])
        ->add('edit', SubmitType::class,
            array
            (
                'label' => 'Save changes',
                'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']
            ))
        ->setData($this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Announcement::class)->findAll())
        ->getForm()
        ;
```

How do I prefill N number of forms based on N number of rows (aka N announcement entities.)

formtype code

```
class EditAnnouncementType extends AbstractType
```

{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('edit', SubmitType::class,
                array
                (
                    'label' => 'Save changes',
                    'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']
                ))
            ->add('id', HiddenType::class, [])
            ;
    }

```
/**
 * Returns the name of this type.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'edit_announcement';
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
$editForm = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('editForms', CollectionType::class,
            [
                'entry_type' => EditAnnouncementType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'required' => false,
        ])
        ->add('edit', SubmitType::class,
            array
            (
                'label' => 'Save changes',
                'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']
            ))
        ->setData(['editForms' => $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Announcement::class)->findAll()])
        ->getForm()
        ;
```

Comment: That didn't work. Received error regarding the Announcement entity not allowing ArrayAccess for "id" in my FormType. included the code for the formtype

Comment: Maybe you didnt understand right, what collections are used for. Collections will be used to save multiple datasets at once. This means, your design is wrong, because you dont want to edit all modals at once. You should only load one modal to edit one announcement. Best way for this is to load the modalcontent with ajax and push the content into the modalbody and then show up the modal.